# Using a for loop in C#

Tags: c#

I want to execute code for a specific number of times but do not know how to use a for loop.

I tried using the for statement in the beginning, but it showed errors.

Here's the code:

```
bool tryAgain = false;
      do {
      Console.WriteLine("5. What is group 8 in the periodic table?");
      string answer = Console.ReadLine();
        
      if (answer.ToLower() == "noble gases")
      {
        Console.WriteLine("Correct answer!");
      }
      if (answer.ToLower() != "noble gases")
      {
        Console.WriteLine("The answer is wrong, pass or try again?");
        string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
        if (userInput.ToLower() == "pass")
        {
       Console.WriteLine("The answer is");
          break;
        } 
         if (userInput.ToLower() == "try again")
        {
        tryAgain = true;
        }
      }
  
  } while (tryAgain == true);
```

Comment: I want the user to only be able to use try again 3 times

Comment: What exactly don't you get about for loops? For loops in general, or specifically related to this code and how to transform it?

Comment: What you've written is a `do` loop, not a `for` loop. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/iteration-statements

Comment: What specific errors were you getting and what did your code look like?

Comment: OT that `if (.. != ..)` can be an [`else`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/selection-statements) (without further condition)

Answer (score 2):

While @boggle111 's answer works as a solution, I will try to write your code out using a for loop to try to explain to you how it works.

```cs
// retries is initially set to 0

// then each time the code reaches the end of the for loop block
// it goes back to the start and increments retries by one

// if retries satisfies the condition retries <= 3
// the block inside the for loop executes again
// otherwise continues after the for loop block

for(int retries = 0; retries <= 3; retries++) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("5. What is group 8 in the periodic table?");
    string answer = Console.ReadLine();    
    if (answer.ToLower() == "noble gases")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Correct answer!");
        break;
        // the keyword break exits out of the for loop it is in, so in this 
        // case will go to the end of this code block
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The answer is wrong, pass or try again?");
        string userInput = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
        if (userInput != "try again")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The answer is ");
            break;
            // here we check if the user DOESN'T want to try again
            // which means we will exit out of the loop
            // otherwise we assume the user wants to try again
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this gives you a bit of an idea of how for loops work, let me know if you have any questions. (Any feedback from anyone on how I answered this question is appreciated)

Comment: Thanks! Helped me to understand for loops better.

Answer (score 1):

Basic C# (or C or C++ or Java)

A `for` loop statement has three parts, separated by semicolons. It looks like:

`for (initializePart ; validatePart; adjustPart)`

For example (the typical example):

```
for(var i = 0; i < max; ++i) {
    // code for each loop
}
```

This gets realized by the compiler as

```
{
   int i = 0;
   while (i < max) {
      // code for each loop
      ++i;
   }
}
```

There's no requirement that you follow the typical incrementing loop variable pattern. The only rules are the the `initializePart` gets done once before the looping starts, the `validatePart` gets validated *before* any code gets executed each time through the loop, and the `adjustPart` gets run after all the code to be looped over gets run each time through the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Use an integer to store how many iterations the for loop has already processed.

```
int tryAgain = 0;
      do{
      Console.WriteLine("5. What is group 8 in the periodic table?");
      string answer = Console.ReadLine();
        
      if (answer.ToLower() == "noble gases")
      {
        Console.WriteLine("Correct answer!");
      }
      if (answer.ToLower() != "noble gases")
      {
        Console.WriteLine("The answer is wrong, pass or try again?");
        string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
        if (userInput.ToLower() == "pass")
        {
       Console.WriteLine("The answer is");
          break;
        } 
         if (userInput.ToLower() == "try again")
        {
        tryAgain++;
        }
      }
  
  } while (tryAgain <= 3);
```

Comment: thank you very much! means a lot its an important project so